# Yes if Due Date is less than 14 days from created

Tags: calculated-column

I want to set the contents of a field named `Rush_Flag` to `Yes` if the field `Customer_Due_Date` is 14 or less days than when the record was created (`Created`).

`Created` is the default timestamp SharePoint assigns every record and `Customer_Due_Date` is a Date/Time field.

I tried:

```
=IF([Customer_Due_Date]-[Created])>14,"No","Yes")
```

but I get the red wavy line.

This is in Office 365

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're just missing one parenthesis...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d")>14,"No","Yes")
```

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx)